# Program broke my windows. Everything randomly minimizes even after multiple restarts

Tags: windows, windows-vista, 64-bit

I just installed LoL (league of legends) on my computer. The problem is that almost every time after I play the game, it minimizes all my windows which is really annoying. What is worse however is that afterwards other programs do this as well.

In the internet browser doesn't minimize but it does loose focus. For example when i type it randomly looses focus and i have to click on the browser window again to it registers my typing.

Is there any way to fix this? What can cause such a strange behavior??

In addition this problem persists even after restarting my computer.

I previously thought it was internet driver. I no longer think so this happened right after I started playing the game and seems pretty persistent. Please read the comments for further information.

This pretty much renders my computer useless. Even typing this takes a huge effort.

UPDATE:

The Problem persists after uninstalling League of Legends

Comment: So, does everything minimize whilst the program runs or when you close the program?

Comment: when i close the program

Comment: So, when does the minimizing occur - always after you play the game or randomly?

Comment: I have tried to end the explorer task but it still manages to minimize me to the empty windows screen.

Comment: I think you should try to roll back your system (System Restore).

Comment: @daverook hopefully this will not brake other things. Like my internet driver. I will do it in 15 minutes if noone posts an answer. Thanks for your interest and insight.

Comment: First, uninstall LoL.  If that doesn't do it, rollback.

Comment: Look in your Task Scheduler for a task that's running every few minutes.

Comment: @DanielRHicks ouch. It turns out that I was wrong about avast. It just so happened that when i turned it off the problem stopped. Today after hours it started again. :/ Maybe i should start believing in coincidences

Comment: @DaveRook Why does it look like its resolved? Its not resolved. Everything i tried so far had only temporary effects and its only because of a coincidences.

Comment: Did you get LoL legally or downloaded from the Internet? In the later case it can be infecting your computer.

Comment: @harrymc lol is a free game. I got it legally.

Comment: Have you tried booting in safe mode and seeing if it happens then?

Comment: thats more of a comment than an answer but yes i have. THe problem is that it turns out that the minimizing is much more random than i previosly suspected (because i stopped using the computer so often as it was unusable so i wasnt able to observe it) Its no longer minimizing my windows and it wasnt minimizing my windows in the safe mode either. I was on safe mode for couple of hours but Im on regular account for a long time and its not happening yet (although this happened before and than it restarted) So its hard to tell.

Comment: If possible, run ProcessExplorer (http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) and try to find anything strange (i.e. apps you did not install). Also check Services (run `services.msc`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After shutting down multiple programs from my computer i figured out that it is my wireless network utility that is causing the problem. Thankfully i do not need to disable my internet connection to turn it off. 
It is the default program that comes with the TP-LINK wireless card for my laptop that i installed. I simply turn it off as soon as i connect and everything stops minimizing.

I am disappointed that I couldn't find this out through a process monitor and had to find out how it works with sheer luck. I will accept an answer that shows how to use process monitor to find out which program uses more cpu power at certain time as the best answer if anyone posts an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 6):

if you had not downloaded League of Legends from the [official website](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/), it could really be a virus.

Even if you did download it from the official website,
and although I never installed LoL and so have no personal knowledge of it,
it is said to
use a constantly running launcher based on IE and Adobe, constantly loading stuff in the background from websites and, as the tech support suggests, has you disable or even uninstall your firewall and anti virus software.

As such, you are very vulnerable to all the various vulnerabilities found in both IE and Adobe,
which both together are the biggest infection vector on the Internet.

Your system sounds like it is infected, so I suggest you read very carefully all the answers
from this thread :
[How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc).

Infection also sounds probable, seeing that LoL had issues with your anti-virus.
For the future I strongly suggest uninstalling LoL.

Comment: thank you. However the problem persists after uninstalling lol.

Comment: Whatever damage LoL did is not repaired by uninstalling it. You will have to repair Windows as explained in the above link. I suggest you start with [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) and several anti-virus scans.

Comment: Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 80% complete.

Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation. (I tried it multiple times always stops at 80)

Comment: Have you run it as administrator?

Comment: yes i I right clicked on command prompt and run it as administrator.

Comment: Then you need to continue with the measures described in the link above. The next step is probably a repair installation of Windows. Mind your backups.

Answer (score 5):

Roll back your system in the OS to the last known time it was working.

In the BIOS, load default settings.

First, run a full AV scan and malware scan then (assuming it is clean) disable all AV/Internet security/Malware scanners etc and see if the problem persists.

Ensure that nothing which isn't needed is loading with your PC (msconfig) and then see if the problem persists.

Take a note of what is running in task manager and see what can be closed (manual and long winded).

Load up into safe mode to see if the problem persists. If it does, review the Task manager / disable AV etc and see if that still causes the issue.

Lastly, if you are feeling desperate, try uninstalling programs which typically run at start up; again, uninstall the AV, obviously uninstall LOL game, uninstall any malware programs etc. I suggest you do this one at a time so you can actually find out what program is causing the error. Check device manager doesn't show any conflicts. Remove all un-needed USB drives too.